Pie Chart Symbology
I have created a map with points represented as pie charts. I would like to offset these pie charts from their locations and have a leader line pointing to the actual real location. Is this possible?

I've just spoofed up some test data and although there is a glaringly obvious section called Leader Lines on the symbology pane when configuring a pie chart symbol, none of the options appear to have any affect on displaying a pie chart symbol with a leader line. So unless I've missed something I would say it's a not a feature supported by pie chart symbols.

Having just said they are not supported, by playing around with size, tolerance and gap I did eventually see a line appear but only after zooming in/out. It seems to me that pie charts don't have an offset/placement property as do labels, so what ever is controlling their display is overriding any changes in the leader line section...

My conclusion as well. Thank you.
